# QT5 mixing QML and opengl draw

Tags: qt, opengl

i want to mix opengl and QML stuff. I used qt 5 beta 2.
I make a minimalist programm for show you the problem :

main.ccp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include "back.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Back b;
    b.setSource(QUrl("ui.qml"));
    b.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

back.h

```
#ifndef BACK_H
#define BACK_H
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QTimer>

class Back :  public QQuickView
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~Back();
    Back();
public slots :
    void paint();
};

#endif // BACK_H
```

back.ccp

```
#include "back.h"

Back::Back()
{
    setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), this, SLOT(paint()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    timer->start(3000);
}

Back::~Back()
{
}

void Back::paint()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 150, 150);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 150, 150,0,0,10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(100, 0);
        glVertex2i(100, 100);
        glVertex2i(0, 100);
    glEnd();
}
```

ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width : 150
    height : 150

    Rectangle {
         x : 50
         y : 50
         width: 100
         height: 100
         color: "green"
    }
}
```

The first picture is correct : 
I have a red square with a green square with offset and a black background.
[picture 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/14898400.png/)

After 3 seconds, the second is uncorrect :
I have only the green square with withe background
[picture 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/690/56801100.png/)

Is someone know what i make wrong ?

Comment: Mixing old OpenglDirectRendering (GlBegin ... GlEnd) with Quick item 2.0 which used vbo is not a good idea. Now I used VBO for my rendering and it's work.

Comment: Could you share your simple working example?

Comment: The code is free and can be see here https://github.com/matteli/histemul